# Symfony Security bundle not loading (properly)

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony 3.2.4 - Using the MicroKernelTrait

I have `new \Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle()` in my Kernel but no security related services are showing up in `cache/appProdProjectContainer.php`.

Basically there is no error but when I try to get a service, it tells me that it doesn't exist.

Example:

`[Sun Feb 19 15:51:26 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'You have requested a non-existent service "security.password_encoder".' in ProjectPath/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:298`

Also, it doesn't look like it tries to parse the security configuration. If I edit it and make a typo in one of the keys, there is no parsing error.

Yes, I did try to clear all cache, of course! (deleted cache folder altogether)

**Update**: When I try to call `denyAccessUnlessGranted(...)` in a Controller, it tells me `The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application`. But I can clearly see it loaded!!!

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you check that the bundle actually exist in your vendor folder ?

Comment: Yep, it is there...

Comment: Does it work in dev mode?  And of course you rebuilt the prod cache after updating AppKernel?  My real question is why was the bundle removed from AppKernel in the first place?  Are you using the Symfony framework?

Comment: I am using the MicroKernelTrait, maybe I should have specified this. Of course I cleared the cache and everything. I'll update the question too.

Comment: I have only read about the micro kernel.  All I can say is that you will need all the security configuration stuff.

Comment: But none of the security configuration I have is being read from the xml config. And not even the standard configuration that (even according to the source code!), is supposed to be loaded by the Bundle during Security Extension load()